# php if resize image add watermark

Tags: php, image, function

Hello i have php function and i need know how to add in this is function in imageresize watermark.

```
  private function resizeImageTo1MB($imageData)
    {
        $maxSize = 1024 * 1024;  // 1MB
    
        $tmpFilePath = $imageData['tmp_name'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmpFilePath);

        $zdroj = getimagesize($tmpFilePath);
        $mime = $zdroj['mime']; 
        
        $aspectRatio = $width / $height;
        
        // Calculate new dimensions to maintain aspect ratio and reduce size
        $newWidth = sqrt($maxSize * $aspectRatio);
        $newHeight = $newWidth / $aspectRatio;
        
        // Create a new image with the calculated dimensions
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

        switch($mime){ 
            case 'image/jpeg': 
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpFilePath); 
                break; 
            case 'image/png': 
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($tmpFilePath); 
                break; 
            case 'image/gif': 
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($tmpFilePath); 
                break; 
            default: 
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpFilePath); 
        } 
        // $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpFilePath);  // Change this to the appropriate image type (e.g., imagecreatefrompng)
    
        // Resize the image
        imagecopyresampled($newImage, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    
        // Save the resized image back to the temporary file
        imagejpeg($newImage, $tmpFilePath);  // Change this to the appropriate image type (e.g., imagepng)
    
        $imageData['size'] = filesize($tmpFilePath);
        
        return $imageData;
    }
```

Thanks

I want add watermark to final image but i was try more solutions and not work :(

Answer (score -1):

this is class that i wrote for my personal use and have all you need. if you need sample, check my github:

https://github.com/hanifzekri/handleFile/tree/main

```
<?php

class handleFile {
    
    public $file, $fileMime, $fileSize, $sizeFormat, $isAnimate;
    
    public function getFile($file) {
        
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            
            $this->file = stripslashes(trim($file));            
            return $this->file;
        
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public function size($format='k', $round=0) {
        $size = filesize($this->file);
        if ($format == 'k') $size = $size / 1024;
        if ($format == 'm') $size = $size / (1024*1024);
        if ($format == 'g') $size = $size / (1024*1024*1024);
        $size = round($size, $round);
        $this->fileSize = $size;
        $this->sizeFormat = $format;
        return $this->fileSize;
    }
    
    function mime(){
        $mimeLists = array('image/png' => 'png',
                            'image/jpeg' => 'jpeg',
                            'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
                            'image/gif' => 'gif',
                            'image/bmp' => 'bmp',
                            'image/x-ms-bmp' => 'bmp',
                            'image/vnd.microsoft.icon' => 'ico',
                            'image/x-icon' => 'ico',
                            'image/webp' => 'webp',
                            
                            'application/zip' => 'zip',
                            'application/x-rar-compressed' => 'rar',
                            'application/x-rar' => 'rar',
                            
                            'application/x-shockwave-flash' => 'swf',
                            'video/x-flv' => 'flv',
                            'audio/mpeg' => 'mp3',
                            'application/octet-stream' => 'mp3',
                            'audio/flac' => 'flac',
                            'audio/ogg' => 'ogg',
                            'video/mp4' => 'mp4',
                            'video/x-matroska' => 'mkv',
                            'video/webm' => 'webm',
                            
                            'application/pdf' => 'pdf',
                            'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop' => 'psd',
                            'application/postscript' => 'ai',
                            'application/postscript' => 'eps',
                            'application/postscript' => 'ps',
                            
                            'application/msword' => 'doc',
                            'application/msword' => 'docx',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' => 'docx',
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel' => 'xls',
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel' => 'xlsx',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' => 'xlsx',
                            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' => 'ppt',
                            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' => 'pptx',
                            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' => 'pptx',
                            'application/rtf' => 'rtf',
                            
                            'application/jar' => 'app',
                            'application/vnd.android.package-archive' => 'apk',
                            
                            //add as much as you want !
                            
                            );
    
        if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {

            $fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mimeType = finfo_file($fileInfo, $this->file);
            finfo_close($fileInfo);
            $explodeMime = explode(";", $mimeType);
            $mimeType = $explodeMime[0];
            if (isset($mimeLists[$mimeType])) {
                $this->fileMime = $mimeLists[$mimeType];
                return $this->fileMime;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } elseif(function_exists('mime_content_type')){

            $mimeType = mime_content_type($this->file);
            if (isset($mimeLists[$mimeType])) {
                $this->fileMime = $mimeLists[$mimeType];
                return $this->fileMime;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function isAnimate() {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($this->file);
        $stringLocation = 0;
        $count = 0;
        while ($count < 2) { //There is no point in continuing after 2nd frame
            $where1 = strpos($fileContents, "\x00\x21\xF9\x04", $stringLocation);
            if ($where1 === FALSE) break;
            else {
                $stringLocation = $where1 + 1;
                $where2 = strpos($fileContents, "\x00\x2C", $stringLocation);
                if ($where2 === FALSE) break;
                else {
                    if ($where1 + 8 == $where2) $count++;
                    $stringLocation = $where2 + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if ($count > 1) {
            $this->isAnimate = true;
            return $this->isAnimate;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function upload($locat='', $newName='') {
        if ($newName == '') $newName = uniqid();
        if ($this->fileMime != false) {
            $fileName = $newName . '.' . $this->fileMime;
            $newPath = $locat . $fileName;
            $copied = copy($this->file, $newPath);
            if ($copied) {
                $this->file = $newPath;
                return $this->file;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function resize($newWidth, $copySuffix='', $compress=90) {
        
        if ($newWidth < 1) {
            return false;
        
        } elseif ($this->fileMime != 'jpg' && $this->fileMime != 'jpeg' && $this->fileMime != 'png' && $this->fileMime != 'gif') {
            return false;
        
        } elseif ($this->fileMime == 'gif' and $this->isAnimate == true) {
            //If you need to resize an animate gif, add resizeGIF function here and remove line blow.
            return false;
        
        } else {
            
            switch($this->fileMime) {
                case('jpg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                case('jpeg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                case('png'): $creation = imagecreatefrompng($this->file); break;
                case('gif'): $creation = imagecreatefromgif($this->file); break;
            }
            
            $width = imagesx($creation);
            $height = imagesy($creation);
            $newHeight = floor($height*($newWidth/$width));
            
            $virtual = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            
            if ($this->fileMime == 'png') {
                imagealphablending($virtual, false);
                imagesavealpha($virtual,true);
                $transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($virtual, 255, 255, 255, 127);
                imagefilledrectangle($virtual, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $transparency);
            }
            
            imagecopyresized($virtual, $creation, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            
            if ($copySuffix == '') {
                unlink($this->file);
            
            } else {
            
                $explodePath = explode("/", $this->file);
                $explodeName = explode(".", end($explodePath));
                $explodeMime = end($explodeName);
                
                array_pop($explodePath);
                array_pop($explodeName);
                
                $newPath = implode("/", $explodePath) . '/';
                $newPath .= implode(".", $explodeName);
                $newPath .= $copySuffix . '.' . $explodeMime;
                
                $this->file = $newPath;
            }
        
            switch($this->fileMime) {
                case('jpg'): imagejpeg($virtual, $this->file, $compress); break;
                case('jpeg'): imagejpeg($virtual, $this->file, $compress); break;
                case('png'): imagepng($virtual, $this->file, round($compress/10)); break;
                case('gif'): imagegif($virtual, $this->file); break;
            }
            
            return $this->file;
        }
    }
    
    function watermark($watermark, $sizeRate=30, $compress=90, $positionX='left', $positionY='bottom') {
        
        if (!file_exists($watermark)) {
            return false;
        
        } else {
            
            $watermarkClear = stripslashes(strtolower(trim($watermark)));
            $watermarkExplode = explode(".", $watermarkClear);
            $watermarkMime = end($watermarkExplode);
            
            if ($watermarkMime != 'jpg' && $watermarkMime != 'jpeg' && $watermarkMime != 'png' && $watermarkMime != 'gif') {
                return false;
            
            } else {
                
                switch($this->fileMime) {
                    case('jpg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                    case('jpeg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                    case('png'): $creation = imagecreatefrompng($this->file); break;
                    case('gif'): $creation = imagecreatefromgif($this->file); break;
                }
                
                switch($watermarkMime) {
                    case('jpg'): $creationWM = imagecreatefromjpeg($watermark); break;
                    case('jpeg'): $creationWM = imagecreatefromjpeg($watermark); break;
                    case('png'): $creationWM = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); break;
                    case('gif'): $creationWM = imagecreatefromgif($watermark); break;
                }
                
                imagealphablending($creation, true);
                imagesavealpha($creation, true);
                
                $fileWidth = imagesx($creation);
                $fileHeight = imagesy($creation);
                
                $watermarkWidth = imagesx($creationWM);
                $watermarkHeight = imagesy($creationWM);
                
                $watermarkNewWidth = floor($fileWidth * ($sizeRate / 100));
                $watermarkNewHeight = floor($watermarkHeight*($watermarkNewWidth/$watermarkWidth));
                
                if ($positionX == 'left') $Xpos = 0;
                else $Xpos = $fileWidth - $watermarkNewWidth;
                
                if ($positionY == 'top') $Ypos = 0;
                else $Ypos = $fileHeight - $watermarkNewHeight;
                
                imagecopyresized($creation, $creationWM, $Xpos, $Ypos, 0, 0, $watermarkNewWidth, $watermarkNewHeight, $watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight);
                
                switch($this->fileMime) {
                    case('jpg'): imagejpeg($creation, $this->file, $compress); break;
                    case('jpeg'): imagejpeg($creation, $this->file, $compress); break;
                    case('png'): imagepng($creation, $this->file, round($compress/10)); break;
                    case('gif'): imagegif($creation, $this->file); break;
                }
                
                return $this->file; 
            }
        }
    }
    
    function crop($targetWidth, $targetHeight, $copySuffix='', $from='center', $compress=90){
        
        if ($targetWidth < 1 || $targetHeight < 1) {
            return false;
        
        } elseif ($this->fileMime != 'jpg' && $this->fileMime != 'jpeg' && $this->fileMime != 'png' && $this->fileMime != 'gif') {
            return false;
        
        } elseif ($this->fileMime == 'gif' && $this->isAnimate == true) {
            //If you need to crop an animate gif, add cropGIF function here and remove line blow.
            return false;
                
        } else {
            
            switch($this->fileMime) {
                case('jpg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                case('jpeg'): $creation = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file); break;
                case('png'): $creation = imagecreatefrompng($this->file); break;
                case('gif'): $creation = imagecreatefromgif($this->file); break;
            }
            
            $width = imagesx($creation);
            $height = imagesy($creation);
            
            if ($width <= $height) {
                
                $newWidth = $targetWidth;
                $newHeight = floor($height*($targetWidth/$width));
                
                switch($from) {
                    case('topleft'): $PosX = 0; $PosY = 0; break;
                    case('topright'): $PosX = floor($newWidth - $targetWidth); $PosY = 0; break;
                    case('bottomleft'): $PosX = 0; $PosY = floor($newHeight - $targetHeight); break;
                    case('bottomright'): $PosX = floor($newWidth - $targetWidth); $PosY = floor($newHeight - $targetHeight); break;
                    default: $PosX = 0; $PosY = floor(($newHeight - $targetHeight)/2);; break;
                }
                
            } else {
                $newWidth = floor($width*($targetHeight/$height));
                $newHeight = $targetHeight;
                
                switch($from) {
                    case('topleft'): $PosX = 0; $PosY = 0; break;
                    case('topright'): $PosX = floor($newWidth - $targetWidth); $PosY = 0; break;
                    case('bottomleft'): $PosX = 0; $PosY = floor($newHeight - $targetHeight); break;
                    case('bottomright'): $PosX = floor($newWidth - $targetWidth); $PosY = floor($newHeight - $targetHeight); break;
                    default: $PosX = floor(($newWidth - $targetWidth)/2); $PosY = 0; break;
                }
            }
            
            $virtual = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            imagecopyresized($virtual, $creation, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
            $option = ['x' => $PosX, 'y' => $PosY, 'width' => $targetWidth, 'height' => $targetHeight];
            $virtual = imagecrop($virtual, $option);
            
            if ($copySuffix == '') {
                unlink($this->file);
            
            } else {
            
                $explodePath = explode("/", $this->file);
                $explodeName = explode(".", end($explodePath));
                $explodeMime = end($explodeName);
                
                array_pop($explodePath);
                array_pop($explodeName);
                
                $newPath = implode("/", $explodePath) . '/';
                $newPath .= implode(".", $explodeName);
                $newPath .= $copySuffix . '.' . $explodeMime;
                
                $this->file = $newPath;
            }
            
            switch($this->fileMime) {
                case('jpg'): imagejpeg($virtual, $this->file, $compress); break;
                case('jpeg'): imagejpeg($virtual, $this->file, $compress); break;
                case('png'): imagepng($virtual, $this->file, round($compress/10)); break;
                case('gif'): imagegif($virtual, $this->file); break;
            }
            
            return $this->file;
        }
    }
}

?>
```